# How should I rent an apartment in England for 5.5 - 6 months as an expat?

Tags: united-kingdom, rental

I have applied for an emigration visa to the UK. I'll arrive in England on 20th April and want to live in Bournemouth until the end of September. During the period I will find a job in London with availability starting in October, and look for a permanent home in London as well.

How should I rent an apartment to live for my initial half a year, considering the 10-day quarantine requirement and also I know no one personally in Bournemouth as well.

Is it possible to rent for 6 months before arrival such that I can get in directly immediately upon arrival for quarantine? If not, what should I do considering that I have only about 5 months remaining before I go?

Comment: You may want to look for either "short-term let" from property agents or a longer-term let on room-sharing platforms (can't give names as usual). Be prepared to shell out a large sum of money upfront though.

Comment: @Michael Tsang Why Bournemouth? https://www.lovemoney.com/galleries/76784/the-uks-most-expensive-and-cheapest-towns-and-cities-to-live-in

Comment: I'm using Bournemouth as a base to prepare for Channel swimming.